# Typo3 permissions of uploaded files

Tags: typo3-6.2.x

When I upload a file (in my case an image) in Typo3 as admin user and set it as a resource of a page the file ends up without public read permissions. This way the image is not displayed since I always get a "403 forbidden" message when I try to open the file in a webbrowser.
I can see the file permissions in Filezilla. When I check the "Read" option under "public permissions" within the file properties everything works fine.
How can I tell Typo3 to set the public read permission by default? Or in more general: How can I get Typo3 to set the public read permission properly?

I'm working with Version 6.2.11

Edit: The suggested file masks helped me solve th eproblem with the permissions. After I changed the masks the links to the images within the generated website point to "fileadmin/_migrated/.." but this folder doesn't even exist and I didn't make an update. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 2):

Go to the install tool and open the section [BE]. There are two options: `folderCreateMask` and 'fileCreateMask'. `fileCreateMask` must be set to `0664`, 'folderCreateMask' must be `2775`.

If this does not work, check (together with your sysadmin) whether the umask on operating system level is set correctly for the webserver user.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That did the trick with the file permissions. They are set properly now. But the generated links to the images now point to "fileadmin/_migrated/xyz.jpg" and not to "fileadmin/_processed/xyz.jpg" anymore. The folder "_migrated" doesn't exist in the fileadmin directory. An idea about that?